# How to safely kill bash/zsh/other shells with its history stored?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh, kill

Shell programs do not react to SIGINT, so `kill $(pidof shell)` can not kill them. When I use `kill -9 $(pidof shell)`, the shell immediately exited as I expected, but the history in the session is lost.

Is there a way to kill a shell "safely" without history loss (just like sending an EOF to it), given that you cannot directly input to it?

Comment: Do you launch shell scripts from console? If yes, can you try to kill only child process you've launched but not parent shell itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send it a SIGHUP – this is the signal used to indicate that the terminal has been "hung up" (including when a GUI terminal window is closed, or when an SSH connection is lost). Most interactive programs will interpret this as a signal to cleanly exit.

A real hangup will send the signal to *all* processes having the terminal as their controlling tty, so you should do the same (e.g. using `pkill -HUP -t pts/1`). This will work whether the terminal is sitting idle at a shell prompt, or whether it has a text editor open, or something else.

*(The term 'hang up' comes from dial-in terminals which were accessed through modems over actual phone calls.)*

Note: If this is a graphical terminal, you do not need to send the SIGHUP to the terminal emulator itself – it'll exit as soon as the shell exits anyway.

---

On Linux, if you have root privileges, it is possible to send fake input to another terminal line using the TIOCSTI ioctl. You can find a small program "writevt.c" which can be used to, for example, send a `exit\n` or any other input as if it were typed on that terminal.